# How to Grab Auto-Generated KafkaTemplate in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

A few examples for implementing HealthIndicator needs a KafkaTemplate. I don't actually manually create a KafkaTemplate but the HealthIndicator requires one. Is there a way to automatically grab the created KafkaTemplate (that uses the application.yml configurations)? This is versus manually creating duplicated configurations that already exist in the application.yml in a newly created consumerFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591092/access-kafka-producer-factory-from-spring-cloud-stream/66591318#66591318).

(S)he wanted to get access to the template's `ProducerFactory` but you can use the same technique to just get a reference to the template.

That said, the binder comes with its own health indicator.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/a7299df63f495af3a798637551c2179c947af9cf/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/KafkaBinderHealthIndicator.java#L52

Comment: Appreciate it as always Gary.

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same requirement of creating a custom health checker Spring Cloud stream. We leveraged the  inbuild health checker(`KafkaBinderHealthIndicator`). But while injecting the KafkaBinderHealthIndicator bean facing lot of issue. So instead of that we inject the health checker holder `HealthContributorRegistry`, and got the KafkaBinderHealthIndicator bean from it.

**Example:**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaHealthChecker implements ComponentHealthChecker {

  private final HealthContributorRegistry registry;


  public String checkHealth() {
    String status;
    try {
      BindersHealthContributor bindersHealthContributor = (BindersHealthContributor)
          registry.getContributor("binders");
      KafkaBinderHealthIndicator kafkaBinderHealthIndicator = (KafkaBinderHealthIndicator)
          bindersHealthContributor.getContributor("kafka");

      Health health = kafkaBinderHealthIndicator.health();
      status = UP.equals(health.getStatus()) ? "OK" : "FAIL";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error occurred while checking the kafka health ", e);
      status = "DEGRADED";
    }
    return status;
  }

}
```